# Why do I get a "ModuleNotFoundError" in VS Code despite the fact that I already installed the module?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to debug some python code using VS Code. I'm getting the following error about a module that I am sure is already installed.

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'SimpleITK'
  File "C:\Users\Mido\Desktop\ProstateX-project\src\01-preprocessing\03_resample_nifti.py", line 8, in <module>
    import SimpleITK as sitk
```

I installed the module using

```
sudo pip install SimpleITK
```

I know that it was installed because I was getting a similar error when I ran the code through the command line, and it was fixed by doing the above. I don't understand why VS code does not recognize that it's already installed.

Comment: Maybe Python path has not been updated in the VS code. Have you checked that? Perhaps closing all instances of VS code and then trying again might resolve the problem.

Comment: Probably not relevant to the problem, but [avoid `sudo pip`](/q/21055859/4518341).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`sudo pip install` is most likely installing globally into a Python interpreter that is different than the one that you have selected in VS Code. Please [select the Python interpreter you want to use](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters) and then install explicitly using that interpreter (if you're not using a virtual environment then use something like `/path/to/python -m pip install SimpleITK`, although I **strongly** recommend [using a virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_create-a-virtual-environment) and to not install packages globally).

Comment: This answer solved my problem. Even though I set up a virtual environment, the integrated terminal was natively pointing at a _different_ Python. So modules installed by running `pip` in the terminal's Python were available to the terminal, but not accessible to workspace files running in it. Any idea how to get the terminal to use the same Python as the rest of the workspace? i.e. The one in the virtual environment?

Comment: If you have a virtual environment selected in the extension (and the extension is loaded), then when you open a new terminal the extension will activate that shell for the virtual environment so that `python` will point to the interpreter you want.

Comment: My problem was indeed this, but specifically because I was using a version of `python3` too new for my libraries.

Comment: What is `path/to/python `? Is it the folder that contains the installation of Python?

Comment: @Julien It's the file path to the Python interpreter.

Comment: Is it the path of the folder or of the file?

Comment: The file that is `python` itself, i.e. what `sys.executable` says.

Comment: For those using Jupyter, [it also supports selecting the Python environment via the kernel picker](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-kernel-management). ([Also covered here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_create-or-open-a-jupyter-notebook).)

Answer (score 62):

After installing a new module via `pip`, and *vs code* doesn't recognize it,
Reloading vs code may work.

Make sure the module is installed inside the virtual environment by creating and activating a `virtualenv`:

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
```

Use the correct way of [installing a module with pip](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/) *(Brett Cannon's article)*:

```
python3 -m pip install new_module
```

Replace the string "new_module" with your module name.

Reload vs code by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, and selecting ***Reload window***.

Now it will know the new module and auto completion works.

---

**Edit**

Consider especially in new distribution like **Debian 12** with newer **python3** always use virtual environment to manage python packages.

Based on [PEP 668, Marking Python base environments as “externally managed”](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/)

For any new project Always create new environmentalism with

```
python3 -m venv env
```

And activate it by running `source env/bin/activate` then install packages on it.
To deactivate current active virtual environment i.e env Run

```
deactivate
```

Comment: Step 2 is done on macOS by pressing Cmd + Shift + P, select **Reload Window**

Comment: I work with multiple venvs all over the filesystem with different project structures (and relative filepaths between the project folder and the relevant venv). How does VS Code know which environment to use? Hopefully I don't have to use the terminal built into VS Code to create the venv or install modules in the first place?

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund I think when you open a file system  directory which cointans python project in vscode, it scan all subdirectories to find virtual environment.

Comment: Do you really *need* to reload VSCode? Just rerunning the Python code should be enough, no? That said, reloading might be the easiest way to do that, like if you have a bunch of language servers running for linting, type checking, etc.

Answer (score 42):

This error is because your VS Code uses another Python version.

The solution is to configure VS Code to use the correct Python:

1. In the terminal, find the current python version:

   ```
   py --version
   ```
2. In VS Code, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (on Windows) then type:

   **Python: Select Interpreter**
3. Select the current python version

Comment: Tried so many options. This worked for me. Thanks. Even though you are in the same virtual environment in the terminal, select proper interpreter inside the environment is the key.

Comment: Use <CMD> + <Shift> + <P> on a Mac.

Comment: Changing the Python in the `Python: Select Interpreter` worked, but it was not the version output by `py --version`

Answer (score 27):

In Mac, correctly selecting the Python Interpreter worked for me.

From within VS Code, select a Python 3 interpreter by opening the Command Palette (⇧⌘P), then typing "Python: Select Interpreter" as the command to search, then select that command. You can also use the "Select Python Environment" option on the Status Bar if it is available (it may already show a selected interpreter, too):

The command presents a list of available interpreters that VS Code can find automatically, including virtual environments. If you don't see the desired interpreter, see Configuring Python environments.

Source: [VS Code Select Interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter)

Answer (score 18):

Faced similar issue and here is how I fixed it. Remember that there are multiple ways to run your code in VS code. And for each way you may end up with different interpreters and environments. For example:
[image]

---

### 1. Creating virtual env and installing libraries

- In my case I opted into ***creating virtual environment*** and doing so outside of VS Code using command prompt:
  `python -m venv .plotting_test`
  [image]
- Following that I activated it:
  `.plotting_test\Scripts\activate.bat`
- Following that I installed additional libraries:
  `python -m pip install matplotlib`
- Following that I made sure to see it was all installed ok:
  `python -m pip list`
  [image]
- And I also checked where for current directory:
  `cd`
  [image]

---

### 2. Point VS Code & VS Code Code Runner to virtual environment

- Opened vs code, closed previous workspaces, opened new folder, created test.py as I was starting new. Pressed `ctrl + shift + p`. Selected ```Python: Select Interpreter``:
  [image]
- Followed by `+ Enter interpreted path`
  [image]
- Navigated to directory from last step from section 1. Found my virtual environment folder created in step one and pointed VS code to that version's python.exe in Scripts:
  [image]
- Verified I am pointed to such:
  [image]
- Saved as workspace so that I can create default workspace settings for this project:
  [image]
- In workspace settings files defined paths to my virtual environment created n step 1 for workspace interpreter & CODE RUNNER(!):
  [image]

```
    "settings": {
            "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:/Users/yyguy/.plotting_test/Scripts/python.exe",
            "code-runner.executorMap": {"python": "call C:/Users/yyguy/.plotting_test/Scripts/activate.bat && python -u"}
    }
}
```

- Reloaded window just to make sure (ctrl + shift + p) = "Developer: Reload Window"
  [image]
- Now run code and run python file should be execute under your specified envs:
  [image]

[image]

Comment: note that might also need to [use the setting `runInTerminal` for `code-runner`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53924384/7860292)

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of proposed answers that suggest changing the launch.json or the settings.json file. However, neither of these solutions worked for me.

My situation:

1. Is Python environment selected? yes
2. Does the Terminal recognize Python environment? yes
3. Can I run the Python code from the activated Terminal? yes
4. Does the code run w/o error when I use "Start Debugging"? yes
5. Does the code run when I click "Run Code"? no

The only solution that worked for me is to:

1. Open Windows Terminal (or cmd)
2. Activate environment: `conda activate <environment_name>`
3. Open Visual Studio Code from Terminal: `code`

Then, "Run Code" (#5) works without any issues.

**Source:**
["module not found error" in VS Code using Conda - l3d00m's answer](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15343)

Comment: I had the same problem. I bet you have a shebang statement at the top of your file.
If you do.
1. Visual Studios settings
2. Under "Code-runner->Code-runner: Respect Shebang" section or just do a search for "Code-runner: Respect Shebang"
3. Uncheck weather to respect Shebang to run code.

Now it will run under the virtual environment and find the modules that you installed using pip! :)

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this problem with VS Code and resolved it by setting my Python interpreter within VS Code to the same as the one in my system path. For example, on Windows, enter

```
echo %PATH%
```

and look for Python.

Follow the process here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter

Answer (score 4):

For mac users

In the terminal check which python you are using by command `which python`. It will give you the path of the python interpreter path. After that type `cmd shift P` and type `Python: Select interpreter`.

[image: cmd shift p]
After that select `+ Enter interpreter path` and paste the path which you got after running the command `which python`.

[image: result of which python]

Answer (score 2):

Try running pip list in VS Code to check if the module is installed, next check if your python version is correct/supports that version of SimpleITK. It may be a problem with the python interpreter that you are using for VS Code (ie. the module may be installed on a different python instance than the one your VS Code is using)

Comment: So now I'm having the problem with the pandas module. I ran pip list, pandas is installed. The python version in VS Code is 2.7, and it does support pandas, so I'm not sure what's going on

Comment: vscode let's you select the virtualenv if it is activated

Answer (score 2):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Mac) to see this view:

[image]

Then select the right interpreter, make sure it is the same Python version and the virtual env you are using for your project:

[image]

Select the right interpreter and everything should work well.

Comment: It doesn't though

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's [Getting Started with Python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_configure-and-run-the-debugger) describes how to install packages where VS Code expects them:

1. [Create a virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_create-a-virtual-environment) with the **Python: Create Environment** command.
2. [Install and use packages](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_install-and-use-packages) with the **Terminal: Create New Terminal** command followed by the terminal command for your OS (e.g. `python3 -m pip install <package>` for macOS).

Answer (score 1):

Check:

- Is Python environment selected?
- Does the Terminal recognize the Python environment?
- Can I run the Python code from the activated Terminal?
- Does the code run w/o error when I use "Start Debugging"?

If the answer to all above is "yes", then, try running the Code using the option "Run python file in terminal" (using the Code Runner extension). And assign a new shortcut for that for future use.

[image: screenshot of Run Code]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I bet you have a shebang statement at the top of your file.
If you do.

1. Visual Studios settings
2. Under "Code-runner->Code-runner: Respect Shebang" section or just do a search for "Code-runner: Respect Shebang"
3. Uncheck weather to respect Shebang to run code.

Now it will run under the virtual environment and find the modules that you installed using pip! :)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a very long time, and had tried almost every other answer. I wasn't using `pip`, so that wasn't the issue. But still VS Code wasn't finding the modules that were installed in the Selected Interpreter.

Ultimately it came down to old conflicts that existed because I switched to miniconda, and VS Code was still looking for anaconda3.

I completely wiped VS Code and its associated files (cache, preference files, etc.) from my machine ([some instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603103/how-to-completely-uninstall-vscode-on-mac)), and installed a clean version.

This now syncs as expected with miniconda.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. If your vscode python interpreter matches your activate terminal environment and you still get "module not found error", the fix is you have to install all packages via this command:

```
conda install -n yourEnv yourPackage
```

Not one single answer lists this command...

Answer (score 1):

This was my weird place on a Mac M2:

1. Is Python environment correctly selected on the notebook? yes
2. Is Python environment correctly selected on the integrated terminal? yes
3. Does the Terminal recognise Python environment? yes
4. Can I install libraries from the activated Terminal? yes
5. Do I find the libraries when loading them in the jupyter notebook or in a python session? no, libraries are missing, even if they are installed with the correct activated environment.

So I figured out (after 20 minutes...!) that **the bug is in the VSCode integrated terminal**.

With a conda virtualenv called `notes` I have the following:

- Integrated terminal of VsCode

```bash
(notes) $ which python
/Users/zzz/opt/anaconda3/envs/notes/bin/python
(notes) $ which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/pip  # WRONG!!
```

- iterm

```bash
(notes) $ which python
/Users/zzz/opt/anaconda3/envs/notes/bin/python
(notes) $ which pip
/Users/zzz/opt/anaconda3/envs/notes/bin/pip  # CORRECT!!
```

For some reason VsCode is overriding `pip` (or `pip3`) to the one pointing at the library frameworks. The installed libraries are all installed in the Framework python, and they are not found when attempting to load them from the conda notes environment, as nothing had been installed there.

I could not find any better solution than avoid using the VScode terminal and use iterm instead.

Comment: For those seeing this focusing on `pip` who might be using Anaconda/conda as in the example lines in this response...  because Anaconda / conda is your primary package manager which you installed Anaconda, it should be you go-to method for installing, and not `pip`. Only involve `pip` when a package isn't available through conda. Things will work smoother and your environments will be more portable and robust.

Answer (score 0):

How to fix module not found error in Visual Studio code?
To Solve VSCode ModuleNotFoundError: No module named X Error Make sure you are running from the package folder (not from package/module ) if you want import module. calculations to work. You can also set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to the path to the package folder.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created a virtual environment, and installed your required packages in that environment, close VS code. For Windows platform, open command prompt and navigate to the folder where your virtual env folder is created. And then launch VS code from there using the command `code .`

For ex: My virtual env name is .imgenv, and its inside C:\py_stuff\projects
So, I navigate to C:\py_stuff\projects and then type `code .`

Now, your VS code should recognize the packages !

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after I renamed the folder containing my virtual environment.

Solution was do delete and recreated the virtual environment.

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into the same issue. I found that if I selected all text before shift enter the script would compile as a file instead of as a single line.

Answer (score -1):

If you have different python versions installed, be sure you install module with right one.

```
python -m pip install <module>
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install <module>
```

Answer (score -1):

Run your environment from a directory not in the users directory. I solved my problem running my environment from C:\Code\ProjectA\

I discovered my problem by running:

```py
IMPORT os

Mycwd = os.getcwd()
PRINT(Mycwd)
```

Answer (score -1):

***.venv/Lib/SitePackages*** is the default directory where Vscode looks for Modules.

This directory is automatically created on creating ***.venv via the command Pallete***.

External modules installed via pip are placed in this directory by default.

Place self created modules inside this folder manually.

[image]