# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3' On VS Code But Normally On Terminal It's Working Fine

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, pyttsx3

While I'm Open My main.py file on terminal it's working fine. But, On VS Code Editor While I'm Clicking On Run Button, In Terminal it's says :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'

How this problem will be solved ?

Comment: Does this solve your question? [Module not found error in VS code despite the fact that I installed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658553/module-not-found-error-in-vs-code-despite-the-fact-that-i-installed-it)

Comment: This Also Didn't Work for me ..... It's Giving Me The Same Error