# My import isn't working and saying no module found in VS code

Tags: python

[Here is a picture of the files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qqqR.png)I have a file with 1 class in it and I'm using another file to try and import it but when I run it, it says no module found. I'm a beginner and still in school and have googled and tried many things but nothing seems to work. I'm using VS code and 3.8.13 python with conda.

This is my code in python im using:

```
import creds
myCreds = creds.Creds()
conn = create_connection(myCreds.conString, myCreds.userName, myCreds.password)
```

This is my creds file:

```
class Creds:
      xxxxx: 'xxx'
      xxxxx: 'xxx'
```

Comment: show us the line you use to import your module?

Comment: the file to import from and the file to import to are located in the same folder?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, they're both in the same file

Comment: Can you show us your file tree so we can get a better understanding of your problem

Comment: Yes I uploaded a picture but since I'm new it would only upload a link to the picture of my files from VS code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658553/module-not-found-error-in-vs-code-despite-the-fact-that-i-installed-it can help you.

Comment: I figured it out thanks everyone.