# Python3 and VSCode ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, modulenotfounderror

I'm working with Visual Code and Python 3 and am getting a

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' error.

error on my laptop. ( A similar setup works on my desktop )

It turns out that VS code is pointing to a python version installed by chocolatey.

I was able to fix it by changing to a different local python installation Following this
[Module not found error in VS code despite the fact that I installed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658553/module-not-found-error-in-vs-code-despite-the-fact-that-i-installed-it)

but the next time I restarted VS Code the problem returned.
Can I either make VS Code keep using the new installation, or otherwise fix the chocolatey installation?

( the problem with chocolatey python may be related to this question, but I'm not sure how to fix it in chocolatey )
[Python3: ImportError: No module named '_ctypes' when using Value from module multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul)

I would love some help with either one of these directions.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the problem of VS code forgetting the python version I selected. The next time VS Code started it stayed on the python version that i selected.  No one gave me a solution for updating the chocolatey version. I should have probably wrote this as two separate questions. I voted your answer up because it is a correct mechanism for choosing the version, but I did not yet try the json settings as the problem was not reproducible, so at this time I will not select a correct answer for the question.

Comment: The python extension remembers your last selection and keeps your last interpreter version the next time you open a workspace. The `"python.defaultInterpreterPath"` setting allows vscode to automatically select the default interpreter when you open a new workspace, otherwise you need to manually select one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to swap interpreter by clicking on the bottom right corner as in the stamp below and select the desired python version.

[image: python_interpreter]

If nothing besides the chocolatey one appears, try to manually locate the one you want to use like clicking on the plus icon and navigating to the python folder.

[image: click_here_if_no_version_is_found]

Answer (score 1):

Choose the correct interpreter for your python extension (*<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> Python:Select Interpreter*).

Execute scripts using the official extension [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python).

[image]

You can add the following configuration to *settings.json* to specify the default interpreter, and then select it in the **Select Interpreter** panel

```json
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "E:\\workspace\\py12\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe",
```

[image]