# I can't use the Pymunk library despite pip saying that the module is installed

Tags: python, pip, pymunk

I want to install Pymunk to learn Python physics simulation, however, while installing it by enter this command into the terminal. I'm on MacOS:
`pip3 install pymunk`
The package is installed successfully, as no errors occur during the installation process (I have installed Pygame the same way before)

When I tried to import the library in VSCode, python said that the module didn't exist. I had even tried it in IDLE, but it still didn't work. Interestingly,  by using the command `python3` to open up the Python shell editor inside the terminal, the module imports with no problem. This is so weird to me, as I haven't found any documentation of anything like this before, how can I resolve the issue? When trying to reinstall the package, pip just tells me that it's already installed. I have installed Pygame the same way before and that worked before

Comment: If it works with `python3`, then try `python3 -m pip install pymunk`. Basically, the same Python environment you use to run your app should be the same environment where you install your packages. It seems your `pip3`, `python3`, VS Code and IDLE, are all using different environments.

Comment: See [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2812520/2745495) for the general recommendations, tl;dr: use `python3 -m pip install <package>`. Then specifically for VS code, see [Why do I get a "ModuleNotFoundError" in VS Code despite the fact that I already installed the module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56658553/2745495). Other than that, you will have to provide more specifics about your environment.

Comment: Thanks, it appears that Pymunk was installed into another directory on my Mac, I was able to fix it with the command provided. Thanks! i am also wondering if it's possible to change the directory pip installs to?