# Can't get VS Code to import pandas or any other module

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, statsmodels

I am trying to set up a class that needs pandas and SARIMAX from the statsmodels module.

I have installed pandas and statsmodels, but I can't get VS Code to import them. I have tried to run `pip show pandas` but it does not return me a location to see if the environment is in the same place as the pandas module.

I read here: https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-fix-the-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas-error-in-vs-code/ that I might have the incorrect environment, but I can't figure out if this is my case.

How do I fix it? Or where should I start to see how can I fix this issue?

I tried:

- Installing pandas in the cmd. It shows as installed already.
- Installing statsmodels in the cmd. It shows installed.

For a weird reason, when I run the code in a jupyter notebook in vs code, it does read pandas, but it won't read statsmodels.

What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a "ModuleNotFoundError" in VS Code despite the fact that I already installed the module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658553/why-do-i-get-a-modulenotfounderror-in-vs-code-despite-the-fact-that-i-already) Look at [Brett Cannon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56675396/4518341) first; IIRC he's the lead dev for the Python extension.