# How to solve the output problem with CodeRunner in vscode?

Tags: python, coderunner

I have my own project with virtual environment. When I am trying to debug code everything executes flawlessly and I get the expected output, but when I am trying to run it with run code option from Code Runner extension I receive the error:

`[Running] python -u "c:\Users\slikm\Pulpit\ytapi\yt_api.py" Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\slikm\Pulpit\ytapi\yt_api.py", line 2, in <module> from googleapiclient.discovery import build ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'`

I have the library which the module is taken from installed on my venv. I read that the problem might be with the interpreter the extension uses, but I don't really know how to figure it out.

Comment: Is the code working when tried in shell? If no, then its definitely missing that package.

Comment: I think I found the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966876/vs-code-code-runner-doesnt-work-with-virtualenvs. Turned out Code Runner did not use my venv.

Comment: Glad it worked!